# Помогите составить Regex в C# для поиска среди текста ключа JSON

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Есть текст в перемешку с бинарными блоками, в котором местами есть JSON строки `{"option1":"{}"}`. Какой составить для этого Regex, что бы извлечь значение в фигурных скобках `{}` нужного ключа `"option1"`? А то не очень дружу с регулярными выражениями)

Comment: Это регулярное выражение должно подойти: `"option":\s"\{(.*)\}"`, а зачем вам регулярное выражение, если не секрет?

Comment: для парсинга определенных значений из достаточно большой JSON из сейва игры, который в перемешку с бинарными блоками. Наверное, в отличии от полного парсинга всего обьекта JSON, этот способ быстрее должен быть, по идее.

Comment: **Регулярные** выражения предназначены для парсинга **регулярных** грамматик. JSON таковой не является. Так что, в общем случае, регулярка может найти не то, что нужно.

Comment: Не проще разобратся с форматом данных? Регулярки для текста, а не для полубинарников.